# Show that $1-i$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

I am using contemporary abstract algebra, by Joseph,
I am in divisibility factor, can you  please provide details step to solve above example with explanations.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: People will not take it well on this site when you copy and paste a homework question and ask for a detailed, step-by-step solution or explanation. I have given you a hint.

Comment: I have a great confusion over irreducible concept, a polynomial is irreducible over a field or ring but here in this above question actually 1-i is actually an element of Z[i] = {a+bi/ a,b \in Z } with a =1 and b=-1...how can an element be irreducible over a ring or a field?pls explain if i am wrong

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
The norm function $\mathbb{Z}[i] \to \mathbb{Z}$, given by $\|a + bi\| = a^2 + b^2$, satisfies $\|xy\| = \|x\| \cdot \|y\|$.
So if $x$ divides $1 - i$, then $\|x\|$ divides $\|1 - i\|$.
What is $\|1 - i\|$, and how many integers divide it? What possible $x$s have those norms?